# SQL Service Broker Error - The conversation handle is not found

Tags: sql-server, service-broker, sqldependency

I have used SQL Service broker and [SQL Table Dependency](https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency) and started SQL table dependency in a table for notifications on table data change. I have given all the permission to database listed in SQL table Dependency document. After some times, may be in idle state it is giving status as "Waiting for notification" .

When I change in table (inserting new record), status is not changing (From waiting for notification) and gives error as "The conversation handle "A705917C-4762-E711-9447-000C29C3FCF0" is not found."

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

First read this comment please:

> There is one very common scenario that results in much more time:
>   debugging. When you develop applications, you often spend several
>   minutes inside the debugger before you move on. So please be careful
>   when you debug an application that the value assigned to
>   **watchDogTimeOut parameter** is long enough, otherwise you will incur in
>   a destruction of database objects in the middle of you debug activity.
>   [Reference](https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency)

---

On the other hand

If you are using `SQLDependency` and get an error like this:

> **The conversation handle**
>   "206A971D-6F25-DA11-B22F-0003FF6FCCCA" **is not found. Invalid object**
>   **name** 'SqlQueryNotificationService -
>   41136655-4314-4536-a477-37156eb628db'.

Then try enable `trustworthy` :

```
Alter database [DbName] set trustworthy on
```

[image]

> The **TRUSTWORTHY** database property is used to indicate whether the
>   instance of SQL Server trusts the database and the contents within it.
>   By default, this setting is OFF, but can be set to ON by using the
>   ALTER DATABASE statement. [more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/trustworthy-database-property)

[Thank to Scott Hanselman for his answer](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/SqlDependancyStartAndConversationHandleNotFound.aspx)

Comment: `SQLDependency` != `SqlTableDependency`. +This is not a valid solution.

Comment: @Marcus, I know it and your point it is not matter here necessarily because although they are not equal but they can have similar problems and similar solutions! Why not?